# CSS content attr() is set, but not showing

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying mo make a badge counter with CSS and AngularJS in my web shop. I have a directive in Angular that adds or removes attribute to HTML element that implements 'badgeDirective'. Like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('badgeDirective', function($timeout){
    return function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
        $timeout(function() {
            elem.addClass('badge-directive');
        }, 0);
        scope.$watch(attrs.badgeDirective, function(newVal) {
            if (newVal > 0) {
                elem.attr('badge-counter', newVal);
            } else {
                elem.removeAttr('badge-counter');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<md-icon class="material-icons" badge-directive="cart.length" 
aria-label="Cart" >remove_shopping_cart</md-icon>
```

The CSS:

```
.badge-directive[badge-counter]:after {
    background: #5da2e2;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(badge-counter);
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 13px;
    right: -1px;
    padding: 0 6px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 13px;
}
```

When I run the site, I see that the badge is in place but no sign of an actual counter:

[image: Badge counter without an actual counter that shows length of 'cart']

I took a closer look in the debugger and found this:

[image: The cart length is there. But not showing!]

Can someone help me with this?
I have no idea why the value is not showing...

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but if you're using custom attributes on HTML elements, isn't it required that they start with "'data-"? As in: "data-badge-counter".

Comment: can you create a sample to demo the problem you're facing? I tried out your css in a codepen, it works fine so that's not the issue with your code. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLjRXy

Comment: have you tried to set some text instead counter value to check that your attribute is actually generated ? note that if value is 0, then it is not there

Comment: @MateBoy Actually, my code is a replica of a existing example http://jsfiddle.net/berpel/S7Rea/ . I replaced 'data-badge-count' to 'badge-counter' and it works. I think i might add 'data-' to the attribute to keep it simple.

Comment: @dommmm here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/berpel/S7Rea/

Comment: @GCyrillus I'm not sure, but it seems that the content type is text/string

Comment: yes it is , it was only a matter of testing if the attribute was there ... alert(newval); would also show if value is >0 to generate that attribute

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get it to work.

```css
.material-icons[badge-directive]:after {
    background: #5da2e2;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(badge-counter);
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 13px;
    right: -1px;
    padding: 0 6px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 13px;
}



.material-icons {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<md-icon class="material-icons" badge-directive="cart.length" 
aria-label="Cart" badge-counter="1">remove_shopping_cart</md-icon>

<md-icon class="material-icons" aria-label="Cart" >remove_shopping_cart</md-icon>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it didn't work. But through some testing i managed it to work. The 'md-icon' is inside a 'md-button'. So I moved the badgeDirective to the button instead. And it worked! Something tells me that 'md-icon' is not the right place to put a counter.